# Прокрутка сайта при наведении на div

Tags: html, прокрутка, mousewheel

На сайте есть div с overflow-y:auto, при наведении на который прокрутка основного контента останавливается, и прокручивается содержимое дива. Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении мыши на блок колесо продолжало прокручивать страницу?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".overflowdiv").scroll(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: не поможет. Кстати пробовал даже блокировать колесо на диве, однако прокрутка страницы все равно останавливалась.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper{
  height:200vh;
}
.scroll{
  width:150px;
  max-height:70px;
  background-color:#aaa;
  overflow-y:auto;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.scroll:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:333px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll"></div>
</div>
```